# Order statistic on intervals

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of numbers `a[0], a[1], ..., a[n-1]`, we get queries of the kind:

output `k`-th largest number in the range `a[i], a[i+1], ..., a[j]`

Can these queries be answered in polylogarithmic time (in `n`) per query? If not, is it possible to average results and still get a good amortized complexity?

**EDIT**: this can be solved using persistent segment trees 
http://blog.anudeep2011.com/persistent-segment-trees-explained-with-spoj-problems/

Comment: Is *k* a constant across queries?

Comment: I don't understand the proposed solution in the blog post you linked, and I think it's wrong. I understand how the solution works with one-sided queries, but not two-sided queries.

Comment: @BuckShlegeris two sided is just a difference of one sided queries

Comment: No, it's not. In the array [100, 101, 102, 103], the second-largest element between indexes 2 and 4 is definitely not the second-largest element between 0 and 4 minus the second largest element between 0 and 2.

Comment: First of all, you can binary search the value (and check that its in the list in log(n) time). That part should be clear. Then you just need to test how many values are there less than the number you binary search for (this is where one sides vs two sided and differencing comes in). And finally a list can be represented as a tree, so the solution applies perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, these queries can be answered in polylog time if `O(n log n)` space is available.

Preprocess given array by constructing segment tree with depth `log(n)`. So that leaf nodes are identical to source array, next-depth nodes contain sorted 2-element sub-arrays, next level consists of 4-element arrays produced by merging those 2-element arrays, etc. In other words, perform merge sort but keep results of each merge step in separate array. Here is an example:

```
root:   | 1   2   3   5   5   7   8   9 |
        | 1   2   5   8 | 3   5   7   9 |
        | 1   5 | 2   8 | 7   9 | 3   5 |
source: | 5 | 1 | 2 | 8 | 7 | 9 | 5 | 3 |
```

To answer a query, split given range (into at most 2*log(n) subranges). For example, range `[0, 4]` should be split into `[0, 3]` and `[4]`, which gives two sorted arrays `[1 2 5 8]` and `[7]`. Now the problem is simplified to finding k-th element in several sorted arrays. The easiest way to solve it is nested binary search: first use binary search to choose some candidate element from every array starting from largest one; then use binary search in other (smaller) arrays to determine rank of this candidate element. This allows to get k-th element in `O(log(n)^4)` time. Probably some optimization (like fractional cascading) or some other algorithm could do this faster...

Comment: this does the job! the exponent is a bit high but still.

Comment: You can do slightly better than `O(log(n)^4)` time. If you modify quickselect, you can get the `k`th item out of `m` sorted arrays of `n` items in overall `m log(m) log(n)^2` time. See my full explanation [here](http://bshlgrs.github.io/2016/06/12/multi-sorted-array-quickselect.html). Applied to this problem, this gets you `O(log(n)^3 * log(log(n)))`.

Comment: @BuckShlegeris: I think you've overestimated time complexity in your blog. Because log(mn) is not equal to log(m)log(n). Which gives O(log(n)^3) expected time for this problem. By the way OP already found a quicker (but more complicated) solution using persistent trees in O(log(n)) worst case time. Also "coordinate compression" mentioned in that link could be applied to the problem in the blog to make its solution deterministic (for the price of additional memory and preprocessing).

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! I've corrected it now. I already know about the persistent tree solution, but I think this one generalizes more nicely to a related question I'm thinking about at the moment.

Comment: BTW, @EvgenyKluev, I don't think that the linked blog post makes sense. Do you understand what "That is for each node in segment tree for range (i, j) : node for (i, j) = node for (1, j) – node for (1, i-1)." means?

Comment: @BuckShlegeris: I think it is better explained in the solution for more general problem "10628 Count on a tree". How do you compute a sum for some segment given an array of prefix sums? Just subtract prefix sums for segment's end and beginning. And this blog post uses exactly the same idea.

Comment: That works for sums, but I don't see how it works for finding the kth element, because I don't think there's any natural "subtraction" operation.

Comment: @BuckShlegeris: it is explained (very shortly) in the last paragraph (for problem 10628). The idea of this "subtraction" operation is to descend two trees at once choosing a path where difference between node counts is closer to k. Or there is a simpler way: just use binary search + persistent order statistics tree; in this case normal subtraction will do; but complexity is O(log^2 n).

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. I still think that it's not totally obvious that this works in O(log n) time; I guess I've have to think about that more carefully some time.

Answer (score 1):

There is an algoritm named [QuickSelect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)  which based on quick sort. It works O(n) in average case. Algorithm's worst case is O(n**2) when input revese ordered.

It gives exact k-th biggest number. If you want range, you can write an wrapper method.