# Find a subset of points such xs sum at most A and ys sum at least B

Tags: algorithm

I'm solving a problem and I reduced it to the following one:

Given `n` points `(x1, y1), ..., (xn, yn)` (`0 <= xi, yi`), <del>and two integers</del> `A` and `B` (`0 <= A, B`) I need to find a subset of those points such that:

1) The sum of the `x` values is at most `A` (`SUM(x) <= A`).
2) The sum of the `y` values is at least `B` (`SUM(y) >= B`).

I'm struggling with this problem and I cannot find a solution other than combining. I would appreciate some ideas.

**UPD**: xi and A are rationals (represented as floats/double). yi and B are integers.

Comment: This is the [0/1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0/1_knapsack_problem) where `x` is the weight, and `y` is the value.

Comment: @user3386109 Sorry I oversimplified the problem. Xi and A were rationals instead. A 0/1 knapsack works well for the integer case. Sorry again :)

Comment: In that case, you have three choices: **1)** brute force O(2^n) **2)** binning the total `x` (reducing the problem to knapsack) **3)** greedy based on desirability `(y/B) / (x/A)`

Comment: @user3386109 1) Yes, brute force works but I need something faster 2) what binning the total means? 3) I think that greedy doesn't work.

Comment: I think greedy `y/x` should work for most cases, because the goal doesn't seem to be to maximize the sum of y. However there might be cases where it doesn't find a solution if there exists only 1 or very few possible combinations of points.

Comment: @maraca Greedy `y/x` doesn't work with this simple case: `A = 2, B = 5, points = [(1, 4), (2, 5)]`.

Comment: I never said it works always, read again, this is one of the cases with exactly 1 possible solution. Also the x are very high compared to the limit so that it is almost a subset sum problem of the x. But if you need several points to reach the limit the greedy algorithm should be pretty good.

Comment: Binning is a way to force the `sum(x)` to be an integer, so that you can use the knapsack algorithm. First, compute the bin size as `binSize = A / 1000`. Then convert each `sum(x)` to an integer with `binNumber = floor(sum(x)/binsize)`. There are a lot of details to work out, e.g. what to do if a large number of `x` values are less than the bin size. And of course, this is still an approximate method unless you can find a bin size that divides exactly into every `x` value.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the distribution and the space available, we could create a ["merge sort" segment tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296624/order-statistic-on-intervals), where the segments divide the `X` range and the tree array-nodes are sorted by `y` values. Then test partitions of `A` such that we can choose multiple `x`s maxed by the right-bound of each part, choosing the top `y` values in `O(log n)` from the segment tree.